# XTTS database migration AIX to Linux

Tags: oracle

I used Doc ID 2471245.1 for migration of 12.2 oracle database on AIX to same version to Linux x86_64, and on phase 5 while importing metadata , impdp fails with ora-39123 and ora-29342. Do you have any idea how to resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: and what is the exact error message?

Comment: ORA-39123 and ORA-29349 Errors in TTS Migration (Doc ID 2591473.1)

Comment: there are 2.7k+ users  ,while importing it looks for those users. Do i have to create all of them before import?

Comment: Is datapump useable between different architectures?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille yes

Answer (score 0):

According to https://rmoug.org/resources/TD2022%20-%20Presentations%20PDF/6-1_%20xTTS%20-%20Lesson(s)%20learned.pdf, you do have to create all users before the import.